# Sharepoint Calendar - Auto-Populate Fields Base on a look-up field on a calendar form

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I'm working on a project where I have 5 fields that need to populated once I select a value from a drop down on a calendar form. All data will be pulling from the same list.

I know that calendar forms cannot be manipulated in InfoPath. I only have access to SharePoint designer. I've googled and googled but, I haven't found anything that will break it down step by step.

I'm fairly new to the SharePoint world. If anyone can put me on the right path that would be great and appreciated.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: As I know if you want to get dependent fields features you need to write some javascript. Whc=ich version of SharePoint you are using it will be easy give you the direction

Comment: I'm working in Sharepoint 2013.